# Python Data Comparisons

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to run a data check comparing columns within a dataframe and returning the % difference; however, I cannot get the conditional aspect of the below code to run without getting the following ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index Item Number')

```
def checks(df):
    if Multi['Masterpack qty'] == Multi['SUBPACK_QTY']:
        Multi['Length Difference'] = abs((Multi['Length']-Multi['SUBPACK_LENGTH'])/((Multi['Length']+Multi['SUBPACK_LENGTH'])/2))
        Multi['Height Difference'] = abs((Multi['Height']-Multi['SUBPACK_HEIGHT'])/((Multi['Height']+Multi['SUBPACK_HEIGHT'])/2))
        Multi['Width Difference'] = abs((Multi['Width']-Multi['SUBPACK_WIDTH'])/((Multi['Width']+Multi['SUBPACK_WIDTH'])/2))
        Multi['Weight Difference'] = abs((Multi['Weight']-Multi['SUBPACK_WEIGHT'])/((Multi['Weight']+Multi['SUBPACK_WEIGHT'])/2))
    elif Multi['Masterpack qty'] == Multi['PACK_QTY']:
        Multi['Length Difference'] = abs((Multi['Length']-Multi['PACK_LENGTH'])/((Multi['Length']+Multi['PACK_LENGTH'])/2))
        Multi['Height Difference'] = abs((Multi['Height']-Multi['PACK_HEIGHT'])/((Multi['Height']+Multi['PACK_HEIGHT'])/2))
        Multi['Width Difference'] = abs((Multi['Width']-Multi['PACK_WIDTH'])/((Multi['Width']+Multi['PACK_WIDTH'])/2))
        Multi['Weight Difference'] = abs((Multi['Weight']-Multi['PACK_WEIGHT'])/((Multi['Weight']+Multi['PACK_WEIGHT'])/2))
    else:
        Multi['Length Difference'] = 'No Match'
        Multi['Height Difference'] = 'No Match'
        Multi['Width Difference'] = 'No Match'
        Multi['Weight Difference'] = 'No Match' 

Multi.apply(checks)
```

Comment: Can you try `if (Multi['Masterpack qty'] == Multi['SUBPACK_QTY']).all()`

Comment: When trying this, all entries in the newly created columns come back as 'No Match' instead of the correct % difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code. The main problems are:

1. You assume `if` and `abs` work in a vectorised fashion. This isn't true. Each `if` statement in regular Python works on a single Boolean value, not element-wise when comparing two series.
2. Because of (1), you continually overwrite an entire series in each of the `if` / `elif` / `else` clauses.
3. Your function returns nothing. Therefore, using `Multi.apply(checks)` will return `None`.

Instead, you can use `np.select` to specify conditions and values in a vectorised fashion. Here's an example for `Length Difference`:

```
conds = [df['Masterpack qty'] == df['SUBPACK_QTY'], df['Masterpack qty'] == df['PACK_QTY']]
choices = [((df['Length'] - df['SUBPACK_LENGTH']) / ((df['Length'] + df['SUBPACK_LENGTH'])/2)).abs(),
           ((df['Length'] - df['PACK_LENGTH']) / ((df['Length'] + df['PACK_LENGTH'])/2)).abs()]

df['Length Difference'] = np.select(conds, choices, 'No Match')
```